# How to get a menu with a list of scenes (for Pie Menu Editor, preferably)

Tags: python, interface, scene, pie-menu

I want to easily switch between scenes using Pie Menu Editor to get a list of scenes in the project.

I found **bpy.context.window.scene**, one that outputs a menu.
I would like a clickable list in the form of a list or buttons right away

[image]